# WPF Expander ignoring data binding after user interaction

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application with an expander where I want the IsExpanded property to change
based on an enum value in my view model i.e. I want the expander to open or close based on
this enum property. I am using data triggers in the xaml to update the IsExpanded property based
on the value of my enum backing property.

```
<Expander Header="Information and Procedures"
                              BorderThickness="0"
                              Margin="5">
                        <Expander.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroExpander}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Item.Match, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                 Value="{x:Static enum:Match.Multiple}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Item.Match, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                 Value="{x:Static enum:Match.None}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Item.Match, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                 Value="{x:Static enum:Match.Exact}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Expander.Style>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                            <view:InformationView Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
                            <view:ProceduresView Margin="0 0 0 0" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                     </Expander>
```

This seems to work until we manually expand the expander. After this it seems as if the data
triggers are now ignored and the manually set IsExpanded property will not change until the user
manually opens or closes the expander again.

I want the user to be able to manually expand or close it, but I want the data triggers to take priority
over the user input.

Note: I don't want the value of Match to be changed by the IsExpanded property. Match is updated separately, but its value affects IsExpanded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the binding is on the `DataTrigger`, not the `IsExpanded` property, so changing `IsExpanded` has no effect no the `DataTrigger` bound property.

Bind to the `IsExpanded` property and use a custom `IValueConverter` to translate in both directions between the source enum and the expander bool.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter

As a nice side effect, you'll also end up with shorter, easier to read XAML.

UPDATE

To achieve the desired behaviour, have a boolean property on the viewmodel for the expanded state, that is bound 2-way to the `IsExpanded` property of the `Expander` and change it in the viewmodel when the `Match` property changes. That way both the user and the viewmodel can modify the state of the `Expander`.

Something like:

```
public bool IsExpanded
{
    get => _isExpanded;
    set
    {
        _isExpanded = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsExpanded));
    }
}

public Match Match
{
    get => _match;
    set
    {
       _match = value;
       switch (value)
       {
           case Exact:
           case None:
               IsExpanded = true;
               break;
           case Multiple:
               IsExpanded = false;
               break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't want the value of Match to be changed by the IsExpanded property. Match is updated separately, but its value affects IsExpanded

Comment: Which values of `Match` allow the user to open/close the `Expander` manually?

Comment: If the `Match` has a value that says expanded or not expanded, there doesn't seem to be any room for the user to have a non-overridden choice.

Comment: Or do you mean that a *change* in `Match` overrides the current state but then the user can modify the state between changes of `Match`?

Comment: The user should always be able to expand or close the expander, however whenever the value of Match changes, the expander should change to the correct state: None and Exact should set IsExpanded to true, and None sets it to false

Comment: Yes, your third comment is how it should behave

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't like this answer. IMO it adds pure view logic to the view model by adding IsExpanded to the view model. Furthermore it doesn't answer why user interaction breaks the binding, which works at first.

Comment: Please see my answer that shows how to resolve this without modifying the view model.

Answer (score 0):

The view model should not depend on the view. That is, you should not add an IsExpanded property as suggested by Scroog's answer.

I resolved a very similar problem by a Behaviour class that changes IsExpanded depending on the IsEnabled property of the Expander. So this implemented in view only.
The following class is just an example and may be enhanced by adding a dependency property that binds to any property of the view model that will be used instead of checking IsEnabled.

```
public class AutoExpandBehaviour 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoExpandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AutoExpand",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(AutoExpandBehaviour),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, AutoExpandChanged));

    public static bool GetAutoExpand(Expander expander)
    {
        return (bool)expander.GetValue(AutoExpandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAutoExpand(Expander expander, bool value)
    {
        expander.SetValue(AutoExpandProperty, value);
    }

    static void AutoExpandChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var expander = depObj as Expander;
        if (expander == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            expander.IsEnabledChanged += Item_IsEnabledChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            expander.IsEnabledChanged -= Item_IsEnabledChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void Item_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var expander = sender as Expander;
        if (expander != null)
        {
            expander.IsExpanded = (bool)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And using in XAML as

```
        <Expander IsEnabled="{Binding IsFunctionAvailable}" 
              local:AutoExpandBehaviour.AutoExpand="True"
              ... >
            ...
        </Expander>
```